# A Möbius inversion in two variables

Tags: number-theory

We have the usual Möbius inversion formula
$$f(n) = \sum_{d \mid n} g(d) \Longleftrightarrow g(n) = \sum_{d \mid n} \mu(d) f(n/d)$$

Do we have (and how do we prove) the analogous in two variables
$$f(n) h(m) = \sum_{d \mid n, m} g(n/d, m/d) \Longleftrightarrow  g(n,m) = \sum_{d \mid (n,m)} \mu(d) f(n/d) h(m/d) ? $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true, and it holds for the very same reasons the usual Möbius inversion holds, namely the relation
$$\sum_{d \mid n} \mu(d) = \mathbf{1}_{n=1}.$$

Indeed, if you assume your expression of $f(n)h(m)$ on the left, you can deduce
\begin{align}
\sum_{d \mid (n,m)} \mu(d) f(n/d) h(m/d) & = \sum_{d \mid (m,n)} \mu(d) \sum_{k \mid (n/d, m/d)} g(n/kd, m/kd) \\
& = \sum_{\substack{m = dkb \\ n = dka}} g(a,b) \mu(d) \\
& = \sum_{a|n, b|m, m/b=n/a} g(a,b) \sum_{d \mid n/a} \mu(d) \\
& = \sum_{a|n, b|m} g(a,b) \mathbf{1}_{n/a=1=m/b} \\
& = g(m,n)
\end{align}

The converse follows from the same calculations, and it holds of course for as many variables as you want.